# Get random record in a set of results

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have a simple MySQL query like this:

```
 SELECT * ,
 ( MATCH (table.get) AGAINST('playstation ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) 
+ ( table.get LIKE '%playstation%') AS _score 
FROM table 
JOIN users on table.id_user = users.id
 WHERE table.expire_datetime > 1375997618
 HAVING _score > 0 
ORDER BY RAND(table.id) ,_score DESC ;
```

If I run this query in MySQL, it returns usually more then 1 record, now I would like to LIMIT 1 and get one of them randomly, not always the same record.

Is it possible?

Comment: What's wrong with adding `LIMIT 1` to your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from <my_table> 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You would quit seeding the random number generator.  My guess is that it is returning the first table id encountered, so the numbers are generated in the same sequence:

```
 SELECT * ,
 ( MATCH (table.get) AGAINST('playstation ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) 
+ ( table.get LIKE '%playstation%') AS _score 
FROM table 
JOIN users on table.id_user = users.id
 WHERE table.expire_datetime > 1375997618
 HAVING _score > 0 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand problem in `,_score` ?
Try this:

```
Select * FROM (
   ***your sql query***
) as t
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```